# C++ pixel-by-pixel image thumbnailing

Tags: c++, image-processing

I have a peculiar assignment for my computer science class where we have to reduce the size of an image by doing the following:

1. Find the average color of a block of n by n pixels (n is given by
   user) by averaging the R, G, and B values for each block.
2. Encapsulate that color into a pixel (just a plain-old-data class).
3. Create a new image from the pixels you have.

When I say find the average, I mean the average color of each of the blocks (like below, only smaller):
[image]

The above image would produce a 4px * 3px image thumbnail. In reality, we would make the blocks ~10px square or so. If the image isn't cleanly divisible by the block size, we are supposed to ignore excess pixels.

The pixels of an image can be directly accessed:

```
pixels[x][y].red = 130; 
pixels[x][y].blue = 200; // etc
```

And images can be created in the following way:

```
image x;
x.createNewImage(xSize, ySize);
pixel** xPixels = x.getPixels();
//then you can assign as above.
```

After trying many different things, I am still unclear on how to solve this.

Comment: start with creating a function which Find the average color of a block of n by n pixels, start with n=1

Comment: I suppose you have a way to load an image.  How do you get the size of the picture ?

Comment: @Christophe Can do this by calling getWidth() and getHeight() on an image object. i.e. `img.getWidth()` or `img.getHeight()`

Comment: @Wimmel This is similar to what I've been trying. What do you mean by "start with n=1" though?

Comment: I mean start with a function which calculates the average of a 1px * 1px block. That should not be too hard....

Comment: I would start with 'n x 1' blocks -- horizontal only.  Then write vertical only.  Then compose: the result is what you want, barring rounding.  Next, optimize.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First assume that the size of your `img` is a multiple of `n`, to simplify.  You could create your thumbnail t in this way (*Attention: I didn't try to compile so there could be some typos left*):

```
int txSize=img.getWidth()/n, tySize=img.getHeight()/n; 
pixel **pi=img.getPixels(); 
image t; 
t.createNewImage(txSize, tySize); 
pixel** pt=t.getPixels();  
for (int i=0; i<txSize; i++) 
   for (int j=0; j<tySize; j++) 
      pt[i][j] = pixel_average(pi, i*n,j*n, n);  // Part 2 of the question
```

Of course you need the average function that Wimmel was suggesting:

```
pixel pixel_average(pixel**p, int x, int y, int n)  // Part 1. of your question
{
pixel avg; 
avg.red = 0; avg.blue=0; // etc...
for (int dx=0; dx <n; dx++) 
   for (int dy=0; dy<n; dy++) {
      avg.red += p[x+dx][y+dy].red;
      avg.blue += // etc... 
   }
avg.red = avg.red / n / n;  // assuming that your colors are small enough, not to overflow. 
// etc...
}
```

Now there's some work left:

- you have to change the code to round up the size of thumbnail if original size is not a multiple of n.
- you have to change the averaging, to be able to cope with partial squares, when you reach the maximal size either in x or in y.
- you certainly have to change the averaging calculation, because in real world, your colors will use the full range of `int`, so you have to find the best way to averaging without overflow (example: use temporary `long`,  make build the wighted average incrementally at each new pixel you take into consideration, etc...)

Comment: I am ignoring any extra pixels if the original size is not a multiple of n. How does this code behave in this situation?

Comment: It's the same: `txSize` is an `int` so that `img.getWidth()/n` is the integer part, and the code above only goes up to `txSize*n` pixels.